# Intermittent Error 500 (concurrent request?)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have a web server with classic apache-nginx for heavy and static traffic. In apache webserver, I use mod_rewrite for clean ugly urls and process php vía mod_fcgid. All works fine, but I have Intermittent Error 500 on **only some** requests, occasionally.

**NOTE:** Error 500 not logging on error.log (not a PHP error), I assume that is a configuration problem (mod_fcgi? mod_rewrite? apache maxclients?).

I see logs and found that error 500 appears with near requests on time, repeated same URL ( 
coincidence?). Some examples with 200/500 error:

```
88.27.x.x [28/Dec/2012:18:57:12 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-1 200
88.27.x.x [28/Dec/2012:18:57:12 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-1 500

88.1.x.x [28/Dec/2012:16:12:32 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-2 200
88.1.x.x [28/Dec/2012:16:12:34 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-2 200
88.1.x.x [28/Dec/2012:16:12:37 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-2 500

200.5.x.x [28/Dec/2012:11:41:00 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200
200.5.x.x [28/Dec/2012:11:41:00 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 500

83.46.x.x [28/Dec/2012:10:55:00 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-4 500
83.46.x.x [28/Dec/2012:10:55:00 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-4 200

200.38.x.x [29/Dec/2012:01:55:24 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 500
69.171.x.x [29/Dec/2012:01:55:25 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200

178.33.x.x [29/Dec/2012:04:48:12 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-5 500
178.33.x.x [29/Dec/2012:04:48:12 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-5 200

201.151.x.x [29/Dec/2012:12:05:31 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 500
79.144.x.x [29/Dec/2012:12:05:34 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200

83.46.x.x [29/Dec/2012:11:11:13 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200
83.46.x.x [29/Dec/2012:11:11:13 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 500
83.46.x.x [29/Dec/2012:11:11:34 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200
83.46.x.x [29/Dec/2012:11:11:34 "GET /permalink/title-clean-url-3 200
```

**EDIT:** I think that, maybe, high traffic for webserver overthrow apache. I create script for count requests every minute on day 28 (format: *HOUR:MINUTE, requests count on this minute*). Errors appears in 11:41, 12:05, 16:21 and 18:57, and not appears high traffic on this minutes (in other moments there are more heavy requests). Can anyone check this analysis?:

http://pastie.org/5593294

Does anyone know where I can continue investigate?

**EDIT2:** I see that on Apache 500 errors are redirected from nginx with 499 error (nginx client close connection). I can solve this?

Very thanks,

Comment: Looks like a loop. Typical cause of most 500 errors. Checking the rules is the only way to find out what's going on, post them if possible.

Comment: Not loops in error. I put rewritelog and don't see errors or loops. URL works fine (I think that a loop fail always, this error appears only sometimes)...

Comment: Do you use FastCGI for PHP? Has anything been solved since that time?

Comment: Yes. I continue with same occasionaly problem, without idea for the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel issue:

I see that made request same URL several times (in very short time) from same IP and same referer. Browsers make multiple calls to server (for request)?